# Best way to implement very simple F# function

Tags: f#

I'm very new to F#, and functional programming, I started learning today! Is this is the best way to implement a function that returns if a string has a digit?

```
open System;

let stringHasDigit (str: String) = 
    not (String.forall(fun c -> (Char.IsDigit(c) = false)) str)

printfn "%b" (stringHasDigit "This string has 1 digits")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SInce `string` is a sequence of `Char`s, one can use functions from the `Seq` module:

```
let hasDigits (s: string) =
    s |> Seq.exists Char.IsDigit
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for functions in `String` before looking in `Seq`. They tend to be faster. This is twice as fast as using `Seq.exists`

```
let stringHasDigit (s: string) =
    String.exists Char.IsDigit s
```

Btw, you don't need semicolon at the end of the open statement.